# Поиск ключа в многомерном массиве

Tags: массивы, php, search

Всем привет!

Имеем на руках такой массив.

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
    (
        [content_id] => 11
        [content_name] => Cat 1
        [parents] => 
    )
    [12] => Array
    (
        [content_id] => 12
        [content_name] => Cat 2
        [parents] => Array
        (
            [14] => Array
            (
                [content_id] => 14
                [content_name] => Cat 2-2
                [parents] => 
            )
        )
    )
    [13] => Array
    (
        [content_id] => 13
        [content_name] => Cat 3
        [parents] => Array
        (
            [15] => Array
            (
                [content_id] => 15
                [content_name] => Cat 3-3
                [parents] => Array
                (
                    [16] => Array
                        (
                            [content_id] => 16
                            [content_name] => Cat 3-3-4
                            [parents] => 
                        )

                    [17] => Array
                    (
                        [content_id] => 17
                        [content_name] => Cat 2
                        [parents] => Array
                        (
                            [18] => Array
                            (
                                [content_id] => 18
                                [content_name] => Cat 2-2
                                [parents] => 
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Суть вот в чем.

Мне приходит ID **14**.
В результате нужно получить не просто массив с ключом **14**, но и его "родителей"(не знаю как правильно).

Т.е. вернуть мне должно

```
[12] => Array
(
    [content_id] => 12
    [content_name] => Cat 2
    [parents] => Array
    (
        [14] => Array
        (
            [content_id] => 14
            [content_name] => Cat 2-2
            [parents] => 
        )
    )
)
```

Если же, например нужно 18, то вернуть все начиная с 13, естественно, исключая 16.

Вложенность массива не определенная.

Что-то никак не получается найти решение.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Чет не могу добавить коммент к ответу @VladD

@VladD, спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @drop_off: тут лимит комментариев, я тоже не могу.

Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так должно сработать:

```
function GetFilteredArray($matchid, $array)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $id => $childarray)
    {
        $filteredparents = GetFilteredArray($matchid, $childarray["parents"]);
        if ($id == $matchid || !empty($filteredparents))
        {
            $childarray["parents"] = $filteredparents;
            $result[$id] = $childarray;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо.
Ругается на [ в строке end($result)["parents"] = $childparents;

Comment: Хм, я не знаток PHP. А как ругается? Мне нужно в последнем элементе массива `$result`, который сам является массивом, перезаписать элемент с индексом `"parents"`.

Comment: Ругается так - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in...

Comment: Хм, а так:

    $childarray["parents"] = $childparents;
    $result[] = $childarray;

? (в смысле, заменить две строчки внутри `if`'а на эти)

Comment: Во. Сейчас разделы пересоздам и точно проверю. Но ошибки точно нет и возвращает нормально массив. А я не мог сообразить как правильно возвращать нужно было массив))

Comment: @drop_off: Я, кажется, потерял `$id` в индексах. Поправил.

Comment: Спасибо.

$result[$id] = $childarray; - $childarray получается возвращает полностью все, включая parents, а нужно только тот массив чей ключ совпал, без остального.

Например нужно вытащить 12, то вернуть нужно только его, без parents 14. Такое возможно?

Посмотрел функции для работы с массивами. Вроде array_slice может обрезать массив. Как вариант тогда считать количество итераций и выбирать срез где совпало. Или совсем не то?

Comment: @drop_off: а, понятно, переделал.

Answer (score 0):

Вашу задачу можно легко решить с помощью обыкновенного рекурсивного обхода массива. Т.е углубляться с каждым вложенным узлом. Далее можно построить связный список( как для всего массива, так и для определенного корневого элемента ) и уже в нем искать "первого" родителя и всех вложенных родительских элементов в главный родительский, затем можно будет просто вытянуть нужную информацию, опираясь на сгенерированную подструктуру.

Comment: В теории я понимаю, а на практике пока не получается) по этому и задал тут вопрос.